# Why were the TIE Fighters shooting at BB-8 on Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, bb-8

> Luke Skywalker has vanished. In his absence,
>              **the sinister FIRST ORDER has risen from the
>              ashes of the Empire and will not rest until
>              Skywalker, the last Jedi, has been destroyed.**
>              With the support of the REPUBLIC, General
>              Leia Organa leads a brave RESISTANCE. She is
>              desperate to find her brother Luke and gain
>              his help in restoring peace and justice to
>              the galaxy.
>              Leia has sent her most daring pilot on a secret
>              mission to Jakku, where an old ally has
>              discovered a clue to Luke's whereabouts....

If the First Order's plan is to search out and destroy Luke Skywalker, why do they order TIE Fighters to shoot at the BB unit which contains their only means of finding him? Doesn't shooting at the droid containing invaluable data defy all logic and directly contradict the entire plan?

If someone kidnaps the President of the United States and speeds away with him, the secret service wouldn't call for an Apache attack helicopter to blow up the vehicle containing the President, would they?

This is similar to the asteroid chase scene in The Empire Strikes Back when the Star Destroyers were shooting at the Millenium Falcon even though Darth Vader wanted Han Solo alive, but I have theorized that the Star Destroyers were actually ordered to shoot at the engine in order to disable the Falcon (but Han just thought they were out to kill them). The same can NOT be said for the TIE fighters shooting at BB-8 in The Force Awakens, though (for obvious reasons).

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming that "Make sure Luke remains a hermit" is almost as good as "kill Luke".

Comment: they may be shooting *at* BB-8, in an effort to drive him towards boots on the ground

Comment: I don't have any concrete evidence of this, but they could just be using ion-based weapons which disrupt electrical systems rather than destroying them.

Answer (score 6):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Force-Awakens.html) is reasonably clear on this. The orders that Hux and Ren have received from Snoke are that the droid should be captured ***or*** destroyed, preferably captured. Ren is obviously *super-eager* to get the droid intact (due to his unfinished business with Luke) whereas Hux, quite frankly seems to not gave a rat's ass about whether his troops destroy the droid and evidently gives orders to use whatever force they deem appropriate to kill everyone in the vicinity and then go fishing in the wreckage to see if the droid survived.

If BB-8 gets smashed, obviously Hux will have to offer his slight apologies to Snoke but that's a small price for getting to see Kylo Ren throw one of his epic man-child tantrums.

> **GENERAL HUX:** ***Supreme Leader Snoke was explicit. Capture the droid if we can, but destroy it if we must.***
>
> **KYLO REN:** *How capable are your soldiers, General?*
>
> **GENERAL HUX:** (with vitriol) *I won't have you question my methods.*
>
> **KYLO REN:** *They're obviously skilled at committing high treason. Perhaps Leader Snoke should consider using a clone army.*
>
> **GENERAL HUX:** (you son-of-a-bitch) *My men are exceptionally trained -- programmed from birth--*
>
> **KYLO REN:** *Then they should have no problem retrieving the droid. Unharmed.*
>
> **GENERAL HUX:** *Careful, Ren. That your "personal interests" not interfere with orders from Leader Snoke.*
>
> **KYLO REN:** *I want that map. For your sake, I suggest you get it.*
>
> **Ren heads off. Hux hates him.**

Comment: "Hux hates him" - is that really in the script? lol - either way: funny

Comment: @NKCampbell - Oh, you have to read the script. The notes are priceless. *Kylo Ren exits, fierce,
          confronts GENERAL HUX (34, **scary**) who awaits him*"